# Return Lambda from Method in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have just begun to use Java 8 and I am wondering if there is a way to write a method that returns a `Function`?

Right now I have method like below:

```
Function<Integer, String> getMyFunction() {
  return new Function<Integer, String>() {
    @Override public String apply(Integer integer) {
      return "Hello, world!"
    }
  } 
}
```

Is there a way to write that more succinctly in Java 8? I was hoping this would work but it does not:

```
Function<Integer, String> getMyFunction() {
  return (it) -> { return "Hello, world: " + it } 
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Get rid of your return statement inside of your function definition:

```
Function<Integer, String> getMyFunction() {
    return (it) -> "Hello, world: " + it;
}
```

Answer (score 24):

You are missing semi colons:

```
return (it) -> { return "Hello, world: " + it; };
```

Although as noted it can be shortened to:

```
return it -> "Hello, world: " + it;
```

Answer (score 7):

I would like to point out that it might be more appropriate to use the built-in [`IntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntFunction.html) in this case:

```
IntFunction<String> getMyFunction() {
    return it -> "Hello, world: " + it;
}
```

`IntFunction` is a part of the [standard API for functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) which defines a range of good to have interfaces, mostly related to Java primitives.

Answer (score 5):

You could write it simply like that:

```
Function<Integer, String> function = n -> "Hello, world " + n;
```

Answer (score 4):

So, the answer for 99% of the cases has been given by @assylias

> You are missing semi colons:
>
> `return (it) -> { return "Hello, world: " + it; }; Although as noted it`
>   can be shortened to:
>
> `return it -> "Hello, world: " + it;`

Yet, I think that it's worth it to add that, if you want to assign your lambda to a variable (to use later).
You can do so by typing:

```
Callable<YourClass> findIt = () -> returnInstanceOfYourClass();
```

And then you can easily use it, one example of such a use:

```
if(dontNeedzToWrap()) {
                return findIt.call();
  }
return Wrapp.withTransaction(() -> findIt.call());
```

Given, things can be even made simpler if the `Wrapp.withTransaction()` method accepts the same kind of Callable's as parameters.
(I use this for JPA atm)