# Can I actually return from lambda to return from method and break its execution?

Tags: java, lambda, option-type

For example:

```
private String test(Optional myOptional)
{
    myOptional.ifPresent(() -> return "1");
    return "0";
}
```

so when I call test(myOptional) it will return "1";

Comment: You can return a `Function`. Does that fit your need? You would call `test().apply()`

Comment: Well, you wrote the code, does it work? Just put it in a class and run it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return Lambda from Method in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771953/return-lambda-from-method-in-java-8)

Comment: The exemple returns another lambda, but it's the same way of doing if you just want to return a string

Comment: Not in Java. I think Kotlin supports that. BTW your code is equivalent to `myOptional.map(item -> "1").orElse("0")`. Maybe you should consider another example

Comment: @litelite no, he is asking about a possibility of terminating the enclosing method and returning the value from the inside of a lambda

Comment: If you found your answer, please `accept` it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't "break" out of the lambda body and return a value from the enclosing method. The `return` used in the lambda works only in the scope of the lambda body.

The idiomatic way would be to levarage `Optional` API properly:

```
private String test(Optional<Object> myOptional) {
    return myOptional
      .map(s -> "1")
      .orElse("0");
}
```

---

Also, keep in mind that `Optional`s should not be used as a method argument:

[Why should Java 8's Optional not be used in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922866/why-should-java-8s-optional-not-be-used-in-arguments)

Comment: Good answer. Better than mine. I'd change the function to definition to: `private <T> String test(Optional<T> myOptional)`

Comment: @Michael hard to say what was the OP's intention here but surely it's one of the valid options

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you! But it's not possible to break the method's execution just to avoit next method instructions to execute, right?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is that the `return` is taken as the return of the lambda function, *not* the return of the 'test' function.

[`Optional.ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) is not expecting to be given a function that returns a value. It expects a [`Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) which is effectively a function which takes exactly one parameter and returns nothing. As a normal function, rather than a lambda it would look something like this:

```
void myConsumer(String s)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

You probably want to use `isPresent` ('*is*' not '*if*'):

```
if (myOptional.isPresent())
{
     return "1";
}
else
{
     return "0";
}
```

or using a ternary operator:

```
return myOptional.isPresent() ? "1" : "0";
```

---

As an aside, you are using the raw type of `Optional`. This will result in a compiler warning. You should declare what type the `Optional` will hold by using generics:

```
Optional<String> myOptional = /*something*/;
```

This will give you compile-time type safety that the `Optional` won't hold values other than strings.

Comment: I think he is asking about a return that breaks from the whole method

Comment: @pivovarit Yep. Your answer made me realise. I'll edit my answer slightly.